# Are some questions better served on stackoverflow or serverfault?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, serverfault

Before ServerFault, *"as a developer"*, I'd probably have asked [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/38181/why-does-my-site-use-the-iusr-account-when-configured-for-pass-through-authentica) on StackOverflow.

Because IIS is still technically part of our developer toolset I think the question would probably be equally well valid on StackOverflow because more developers would have encountered the type of issue encountered in the question.

It feels like an overlapping question to me. What does the community think?

Comment: I think there are potentially a lot of things that can be on both, and I'm sure zealots will be moving things a lot, but there needs to be some guidance as to when it's appropriate for one site versus the other.

Comment: Let's have a overlapping.stackoverflow.com ! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a tricky one; until you know what was wrong, it is ***hard to know*** whether it is a server or development issue. Either (or both) may be the case. And if we knew the problem already we probably wouldn't be asking.

I think this is a narrow set of cases, though. As long as the question explains **why** it is relevant to the given site (i.e. there is a reason to suspect server and/or development, I can't see a problem with it being on either (or even both).

Comment: There's seems the be a fair few IIS7 config type questions over on SO. I guess my danger is being downvoted or closed because I also asked on SF. I'll suck it and see and stick the question on SO, what's the worst that can happen?

Answer (score 1):

If your not sure you could either post it on the one you think is most applicable and if you don't get an answer post it on the other.

In the first instance make it clear that you're not 100% sure which site the question should be on and explain why you think "this" site is most appropriate. In the second case explain that you have already posted it on the "other" site. I'd link the questions so hopefully it won't get closed as "belongs on SO/SF".

Answer (score 1):

Something as broad as "IIS7" is hard to judge because there are specific parts of IIS which could be asked on either site. If you are having problems with setup, installation, and maintenance, that would obviously lean more towards ServerFault. If you have an issue with getting it working for serving up a website, sounds more like StackOverflow.

Mostly it should just be a judgment call and you go from there. If a good deal of the community feels that it is in the wrong spot, they probably won't hesitate to tell you about the error of your ways.

Comment: "they probably won't hesitate to tell you about the error of your ways" - I'm sure they won't :)

Comment: Just out of interest, how would you deal with the specific case in hand?

Comment: Kev: In that instance I would have agreed with your placing of it on ServerFault, although I can definitely see why there would be some ambiguity as to where it belongs.